# How to convert Jar to exe or msi package to remotely deploy?

Tags: java, deployment, jar

**Project:** a simple swing application using Java 7.

**Objective:** Distribute as a .exe or MSI so that i can release patch & updates to the application.

I am aware of the fact there many utilities to convert a jar file to executable .exe my questions are :

1. I have used Java 7 for the project & the target systems don't have
   java 7 - so i have to include jre 7 with my package ? Hope the 3
   party lib i used gets compiled along with the jar.
2. I am going to remote depoly the package to the target system is it
   possible ?
3. I have to update the installed application remotely by deploying the
   update packages can this be done ?

Comment: *"Distribute .. so that i can release patch & updates to the application."*  Does the app. have a GUI?  Do the users have net (or intranet) access?  If so, [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can do what needs doing.  Edit: Sorry, JWS has a bit of trouble with the 'remote' part of it (point 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, distributing it as an **.EXE** or **.MSI** file won't provide you with the ability of releasing patches/updates and to process them remotely. For that you will need to implement your own Update Manager for that specific application, connected to your remote repository. There are several questions in SO discussing that matter:

1. [How Should I Implement an Auto Updater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232347/how-should-i-implement-an-auto-updater)
2. [How to Implement Auto Updater in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443269/how-to-implement-auto-update-in-java)
3. [Best way to update products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906552/best-way-to-update-products?rq=1)

If you dig a bit more in that subject you will find sooner or later than, even when 'auto-updates' is a requirement, you don't need an **.EXE** or **.MSI** file for that, just think about Eclipse IDE, it is distributed as a **.ZIP** file and it has its own Update Manager.

However, I think that when you say "distribute as .exe or MSI" you really mean distribute it as an auto-installer (which is not the same as an auto-updater). For that you have several options:

1. If you just want to distribute to Windows platforms (which is a shame, since Java can run in a lot of platforms) then try with the famous [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) or the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/).
2. If you want it to be cross-platform (as I would recommend), then in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276091/installer-generator-written-in-java) you'll find a list with several tools to get that.

Comment: yes you are bang on. I am trying to do a auto installation. so when i use auto installion is it possible to update the installed application later ? I will using IBM tivoli software distribution to remotely deploy the application